# Firebase real time database access data array from deleted node

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am deleting a FRTDB node, I want to access deleted data from that node. the functions looks as follow:

```
exports.events = functions.database.ref('/events/{eventId}').onWrite(async (change, context) => {
  const eventId = context.params.eventId
  if (!change.after.exists() && change.before.exists()) {
    //data removed
    return Promise.all([admin.database().ref(`/events/${eventId}/dayofweek`).once('value')]).then(n => {
      const pms = []
      const days = n[0]
      days.forEach(x => {
        pms.push(admin.database().ref(`${change.before.val().active ? 'active' : 'inactive'}/${x.key}/${eventId}`).set(null))
      })
      return Promise.all(pms)
    });
   else {
    return null;
  }
})
```

The probem I am having is that

> admin.database().ref(`/events/${eventId}/dayofweek

do not loop the data because it seems data is no longer there so the forEach is not working. How can I get access to this data and get to loop the deleted data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data that was deleted from the database is actually included in the call to your Cloud Function. You can get if from `change.before`.

```
exports.events = functions.database.ref('/events/{eventId}').onWrite(async (change, context) => {
  const eventId = context.params.eventId
  if (!change.after.exists() && change.before.exists()) {
    //data removed
    days = change.before.val().dayofweek;
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you won't be able to read data that was just deleted.  The function runs **after** the delete is complete.  If you want to get the data that was just deleted, you're supposed to use `change.before` as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value):

> The Change object has a `before` property that lets you inspect what was
> saved to Realtime Database before the event. The before property
> returns a DataSnapshot where all methods (for example, val() and
> exists()) refer to the previous value. You can read the new value
> again by either using the original DataSnapshot or reading the `after`
> property. This property on any Change is another DataSnapshot
> representing the state of the data after the event happened.